# Помогите Java.Applet

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    Label lb;
    TextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
    Button bt;
    int size, size1, size2, s1, s, s2, total;

    float percSize, percSize1, percSize2;

    public void init() {

        setLayout(null);

        lb = new Label("Enter Statistic Figures");
        tf1 = new TextField();
        tf2 = new TextField();
        tf3 = new TextField();

        bt = new Button("Draw");
        bt.addActionListener(this);

        lb.setBounds(20,40,140,20);
        tf1.setBounds(170,40,40,20);
        tf2.setBounds(220,40,40,20);
        tf3.setBounds(270,40,40,20);
        bt.setBounds(380,40,60,20);

        add(lb);
        add(tf1);
        add(tf2);
        add(tf3);
        add(bt);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        //od lewej,od gory, pochylenie=200, szerokosc=200 (proporcjonalnie!), od kata, rozsz. o kat

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,0,s);

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,s,s1);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,s1,s2);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        size = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        size1 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        size2 = Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText());

        total = size+size1+size2;

        percSize = (size * 100.0f) / total;
        percSize1 = (size1 * 100.0f) / total;
        percSize2 = (size2 * 100.0f) / total;

        s = percSize*360/100;
        s1 = percSize1*360/100;
        s2 = percSize2*360/100;

        repaint();

    }
}
```

Не работает код ошибки при компиляции + не выводит саму диаграмму ( Не рисует )
**При компиляции в этой строчке кода
s = percSize*360/100;
Выдает ошибку possible lossy conversion from float to int**

Comment: Дополнил , вписал ошибку которую выдает

Comment: `possible lossy conversion from float to int` - говорит лишь о том, что потеряется точность числа, так как оно конвертнется в целое, а значит откинет все, что после запятой.....нужно понять устраивает ли тебя целое или хочется сохранить точность

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй эти три строки на

```
s = (int) (percSize*360/100);
s1 = (int) (percSize1*360/100);
s2 = (int) (percSize2*360/100);
```

Comment: Спасибо , огромное код заработал и откомпилировался , но теперь не рисует саму диаграмму , буду очень благодарен если поможете , так как тему с апплетами в универе не очень понял

Comment: Я скопировал себе у меня заработал. 
1) Как ты запускаешь? Если через html брось исходник html который используешь. 
2) текстовые поля и кнопку видишь? Вписываешь в эти поля цифры(допустим 1 в каждый) и нажимаешь кнопку. 
3) если все делаешь как нписано в пункте 2 Посмотри не выходит ли ошибка в консоль?

Comment: Запускаю через BlueJ

Comment: У тебя именно строит диаграмму при любых введенных значниях? ( Имею ввиду полностью круг строит)

Comment: Так у тебя логика не работает. А я думаю аплет не показывается. В последнем **fillArc** должно быть не от s1 а от s+s1. Потому что s1 начинается не с нуля. 

`g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillArc(100, 200, 400, 400, s1+s, s2);`

Comment: Изменил , ситуевина та же , ввод данных , после чего кнопка Draw и ноль на массу

Comment: Я не понимаю. У тебя показывает круг поделенный на три части когда вводишь 1,1,1 или нет?
Запусти в аплет в браузере.

Comment: Вообще ничего не выводит при вводе данных :(

Comment: Может будет удобнее VK или FB?

Comment: Могу оставить свои данные в долгу не останусь )

Comment: ну давай контакты посылай. Желательно скайп. быстрее будет

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test extends Applet implements ActionListener {
Label lb;
TextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
Button bt;
int size, size1, size2, s1, s, s2, total;

float percSize, percSize1, percSize2;

public void init() {

    setLayout(null);

    lb = new Label("Enter Statistic Figures");
    tf1 = new TextField();
    tf2 = new TextField();
    tf3 = new TextField();

    bt = new Button("Draw");
    bt.addActionListener(this);

    lb.setBounds(20,40,140,20);
    tf1.setBounds(170,40,40,20);
    tf2.setBounds(220,40,40,20);
    tf3.setBounds(270,40,40,20);
    bt.setBounds(380,40,60,20);

    add(lb);
    add(tf1);
    add(tf2);
    add(tf3);
    add(bt);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {


    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,0,s);

    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,s,s1);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillArc(100,200,400,400,s1+s,s2);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    size = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
    size1 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
    size2 = Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText());

    total = size+size1+size2;

    s =  (int) (percSize*360/100);
    s1 = (int) (percSize1*360/100);
    s2 = (int) (percSize2*360/100);

    repaint();

}
}
```

Вот весь код который получился